# Cofactor multiplied with another row

Tags: matrices, determinant

Why is it that when I add up the product of cofactors for one row and a corresponding element of any other row , the answer is 0?
For example:
[image]

This seems to work for all matrices but I'm unable to figure out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because what you are doing is essentially finding the determinant of a matrix with two identical rows, which is always singular.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify it further, take a matrix $A$. Make another matrix $B$ by copying $A$'s first row to second row (in effect throwing away $A$'s second row).

Now the determinant of $B$, $\vert B \vert$, can be written as $a_{21} \times C_{21} + a_{22} \times C_{22} + \ldots + a_{2n} \times C_{2n}$.

Since $a_{2j} = a_{1j}$ $\forall j$ (i.e., second row is same as first row), $\vert B \vert = a_{11} \times C_{21} + a_{12} \times C_{22} + \ldots + a_{1n} \times C_{2n}$.

Also since $B$ has two identical rows, we have $\vert B \vert = 0$. 
Hence, $a_{11} \times C_{21} + a_{12} \times C_{22} + \ldots + a_{1n} \times C_{2n} = 0$